# Is it possible to check condition coverage with gcov?

Tags: c, unit-testing, gcc, code-coverage, gcov

By condition coverage, I mean like in the definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_coverage#Coverage_criteria). I didn't find such option in the documentation [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-Gcov.html#Invoking-Gcov). An option that gives me relevant statistics which I can parse easily condition coverage is also fine - but I can't find one.

Comment: You need some external tool, gcov cannot do that AFAIK. CBMC (The C Bounded Model Checker) is capable of determining MC/DC coverage etc.

Comment: @MortenJensen , There isn't even an option of gcov which will give me information that I can parse from it the condition coverage?

Comment: I don't think gcov can do that. If you just want condition coverage, there are ways around that. You could implement macros for branch-statements `if`, `while` etc., and save the result - check this out: http://www.macroexpressions.com/dl/C%20code%20unit%20testing%20on%20a%20shoestring.pdf - I've used `pycparser` to do the instrumentation instead of the preprocessor - that works even better.

Comment: In the source code annotation produced by `gcov` you can see which code was never executed.

Comment: `gcov -a` more or less handles it. Try it on a few examples to see if that's good enough for you.