# Does Branch coverage implies Condition Coverage?

Tags: matlab, mingw, code-coverage, gcov

i need some help understanding and right interpreting the gcov results.

Lines executed: 25% of 24
Branches executed:30% of 20
Taken at least once: 15% of 20
Calls executed: 50% of 2

Lines executed gives me the Statement Coverage.
Branches executed gives me the decision coverage and condition coverage

Am I right if i am saying that 100% Branch coverage implies 100% Decision Coverage and Condition Coverage?

Because my understanding is that the if statement if(a<1 || b>2){...}else{...} has not two branches but 4 because i have two conditions. That means if i am going through all 4 branches i should have the condition coverage or does the branch coverage provides no information about the condition coverage

Thanks for your help.

Cheers

Comment: i thought that a branch for gcov is an arc and an arc can be created by for, if, while, switch/case, &&, ||, ? : . This is what i understood from here : https://gcovr.com/en/stable/faq.html Therefore the example which i showed in the post should have 4 arcs. "branches" which should therefore also cover the condition coverage or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking specifically about the gcov tools, the branch coverage is really counting the points at which the end of each basic block is reached.  See [Understanding branches in gcov files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7060005/1256452).

*Condition* coverage is something different.  See [Is it possible to check condition coverage with gcov?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48260434/1256452)  (The answer is no, it's not, at least not with *just* gcov.)  As [Marc Gilsse's comment notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48260434/is-it-possible-to-check-condition-coverage-with-gcov#comment83506248_48260434), you can use `gcov -a` to count executions through each basic block, and use that as a reasonable approximation—but it's not the same thing.

C++'s exceptions make dealing with branch coverage messy; see [LCOV/GCOV branch coverage with C++ producing branches all over the place](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42003783/1256452).  This means you won't necessarily be able to cover all branches in the first place.

See also, e.g., [Understanding blocks in gcov files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55906426/1256452).